# What is the difference between a vector and matrix in python?

Tags: python

If `X = dataset.iloc[:,1].values` is a vector.

Then why `X = dataset.iloc[:,1:2].values` is a matrix. How this works?

Comment: It is that same as in math: dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The same reason they are that way in math; a vector is just a 1xN matrix.